# How to change the default accordion svg icon on bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-5

I would like to change the default bootstrap icon for accordions

Instead of the default arrow icon, I would like to use the `<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i>` and the `<i class="bi bi-dash-circle"></i>` [bootstrap icons](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/).

One icon when accordion it's collapsed and the other icon when it's not collapsed.

Desired result:

[image: desiredresult]

Current result:

[image: currentresult]

As far as I know the default arrow icon comes from here (truncated):

```
.accordion-button::after {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);

}
```

And it's basically set as a background-image.

When the user toggles, the background image is rotated 180 degrees:

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%230c63e4'%3e%3cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    transform: rotate(
-180deg);
}
```

The first thing that comes to my mind is to replace both svg's for the desired bootstrap icons svg's and remove the rotation.

So I tried to replace the current SVG with the bootstrap icon svg:

```
.accordion-button::after {
    order: -1;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23212529' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z' d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
    background-color: white;
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work. Did I put the svg code wrong? is there a better way to achieve this?

[LIVE JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/42/)

(feel free to edit the code and try the svg code of any bootstrap icons)

Comment: The svg img url seems not correct ~! are you sure ?

Comment: No I'm not sure! I just copied the svg here: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/plus-circle/ and tried to adapt it. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, basically we need to encode those bootstrap icons svg's in order to use it as css background-image.

[Here is an online solution](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) that I found.

So now, with this code:

```
.accordion-button::after {
    order: -1;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='currentColor' class='bi bi-plus-circle' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Cpath d='M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-color: white;
}
```

It works!

Comment: nice~! it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

**Sass option:**

You didn't mention if you're using sass (that I could see) but if you are, Bootstrap 5 provides the 2 sass variable for accordion icon states which you can override:

```
$accordion-button-icon:         url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='#{$accordion-icon-color}'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>");
$accordion-button-active-icon:  url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='#{$accordion-icon-active-color}'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/></svg>");
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/accordion/#variables

Bootstrap 5 has an `escape_svg` function too (i think that's what it's called) to escape the characters in the SVG too.

You'd need to include your variable overrides as outlined here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/sass/#variable-defaults

Might seem a lot of work but once it's setup with sass it becomes easier to override & extend things in Bootstrap this way.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me try this solution

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
background-color: #d2153d;
background-image: url("/img/Home/FAQ/arrow-up.png");
transform: rotate(360deg);
background-size: auto;
background-position: center;
}

.accordion-button.collapsed::after {
background-image: url("/img/Home/FAQ/arrow-down.png");
background-size: auto;
background-position: center;
}

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #d2153d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it works great. I was not aware of `background-size: auto` and `background-position: center` they are important. You saved me lots of research.